# Error : Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC in Selector Of NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a method like this :

```
-(void)fastTapCartBack:(NSString*)ActionType
```

And I want to use it as selector in NSTimer like this :

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:[self performSelector:@selector(fastTapCartBack:) withObject:@"FAST"] userInfo:nil repeats:NO]
```

But It have Error :

**Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL _Nonnull' is disallowed with ARC**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a second parameter in the target / action pattern.

However in case of `NSTimer` there is a very suitable solution, the `userInfo` parameter

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                              target:self 
                                            selector:@selector(fastTapCartBack:)
                                            userInfo:@"FAST" 
                                             repeats:NO];
```

and get the information in the selector method

```
-(void)fastTapCartBack:(NSTimer *)timer {
     NSString *info = (NSString *)timer.userInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a method call `[self performSelector:@selector(fastTapCartBack:) withObject:@"FAST"]` as selector, this is not allowed by Objective-C

**replace this**

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:[self performSelector:@selector(fastTapCartBack:) withObject:@"FAST"] userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**By this**

**You should use NSInvocation way**

```
NSMethodSignature * signature = [ViewController instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(fastTapCartBack:)];
NSInvocation * invocation = [NSInvocation
             invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(fastTapCartBack:)];
NSString * argument = @"FAST";
[invocation setArgument:&argument atIndex:2];

self.timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Yea it works, but I need to define second argument of my method. how define my selector with specified second argument ?

Comment: @SaMiGiMiX did you test my answer? using `NSInvocation`?

Comment: yes but it have error and thread breakpoint on NSInvocation * invocation